# Using FbxIOSettings in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

im trying to use FbxIOSettings in python , here is my code:

```
    fbxManager = fbx.FbxManager.Create()
    ios = fbx.FbxIOSettings.create(fbxManager ,FbxIOSettings.IOSROOT) 
    fbxManager.SetIOSettings(ios)
```

[my libaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRcQf.png)

**and im getting this error:**
ios = fbx.FbxIOSettings.create(fbxManager ,FbxIOSettings.IOSROOT)
AttributeError: type object 'FbxIOSettings' has no attribute 'create'

libaries: